# Using Mighty Crusader Expertise with a sword and board Paladin

Tags: dnd-4e

Mighty Crusader Expertise, just released, reads:

> Benefit: When you are using a holy symbol and
>   wielding a melee weapon in two hands, you gain a
>   +1 feat bonus to weapon attack rolls you make with
>   the weapon and a +1 feat bonus to implement attack
>   rolls you make with the holy symbol. These bonuses
>   increase to +2 at 11th level and +3 at 21st level.
>
> Also, when you use two hands to wield a melee
>   weapon with which you have proficiency, ranged and
>   area attacks that you make with a holy symbol do not
>   provoke attacks of opportunity.

I would like to take advantage of this as a sword&board paladin by using the versatile property of a longsword or equivalent. What feats, type of shield, or magic items do I need to have to be able to use a free action to switch between shield use and using my sword two-handed?

Comment: And while "just house rule it" is what I'm doing in my game, it's not actually a valid answer to this question and will be downvoted.

Comment: Interesting question. The answer could also possibly help me with my Sword&Board Cunning Bard (who is also a candidate for playtesting the new Battle Song Expertise feat). ^^

Comment: As a side note, I am hugely unimpressed with these feats. They're all dancing around the math fix, and some of them are incredibly silly.

Comment: Am I missing something here?  Can't you just use a small shield which straps to your arm and not your hand? The free action would just be grasping the sword in two hands.

Comment: @GMNoob can you cite the rules showing that the light shield can be used like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 267 of the Rules Compendium:

> **Using a Shield:** To use a shield, a creature must strap it to the
> forearm. doing so is a standard action, unless otherwise noted.
> Removing a shield is also a standard action.
>
> **Light Shield**: While using
> a light shield, a creature can use its shield hand for other purposes,
> such as holding another item or climbing, but the can't make attacks
> with that hand or with anything it is holding in that hand.

It would seem to me that you can use a free action to grab the hilt of a versatile weapon with your shield hand, since it is attached to your forearm.  I believe at this point you lose the benefit of the shield, but you can use your holy symbol for the feat.

I can see how someone might read the rules to say that you can't use the weapon in a versatile manner at all while wearing a shield, but to me since there is no attack being made with the versatile weapon, it doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: -1. I really disagree with this interpretation. Versatile property allows the wielder to use the weapon two-handed. That is: if you leverage the Versatile property you are effectively wielding a two-handed weapon. You can wield a two-handed weapon while having a light shield strapped yo your arm, but _you can't attack with it_ as long as the shield is worn.

Comment: +1 while the character cannot attack with the weapon, the character can attack with her holy symbol and counts as wielding the weapon 2h. It's fiddly but...

Comment: It's clear that you can *hold* the sword in your shield hand. It's less clear that you can *wield* the sword in your shield hand. You could argue (though it seems way too pedantic) that to *wield* you must be able to attack, and so the combo doesn't work. In the end, I say go for it.

Comment: Erik you are correct, I wasn't clearly answering the question at hand, I've edited it to clarify.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks to @Brian Ballsun-Stanton for pointing the torchlight on the holy symbol attack. -1 converted to +1.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best item in these cases is the [Winged Shield](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=3072)<sup>DDI</sup>. It floats around you needing no arm to be attached to (even if it occupies the Arms magic item slot as usual).

Earlier you may want to try a [Shielding Blade](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=2474)<sup>DDI</sup> which grants a +1 shield bonus to AC in order to catch up for the missing shield. Of course this option is not as palatable as a true shield (no Reflex bonus and no feat-, power- or feature-related boon).